Ocultar un Div Class en página
Trato de ocultar el siguiente div, perteneciente a esta web:
<div class="tutor-col-lg-6 tutor-col-xl-4 tutor-mb-16 tutor-mb-lg-32">

Adjunto imagen de la web
La única forma donde consigo hacerlo es definindo display: none; en el campo element.style {} por lo que deseo ocultar este div usando el "code snnipet" en wordpress, pero no sé qué tipo de código debo  elegir (CSS o HTML).
He intentado con lo siguiente, pero me descuadra la web:


<div class="tutor-col-lg-6 tutor-col-xl-4 tutor-mb-16 tutor-mb-lg-32" style="
    display: none;
">
            <div class="tutor-card">
                <div class="tutor-d-flex tutor-flex-lg-column tutor-align-center tutor-text-lg-center tutor-px-12 tutor-px-lg-24 tutor-py-8 tutor-py-lg-32">
                    <span class="tutor-round-box tutor-mr-12 tutor-mr-lg-0 tutor-mb-lg-12">
                        <i class="tutor-icon-trophy" area-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    <div class="tutor-fs-3 tutor-fw-bold tutor-d-none tutor-d-lg-block">0</div>
                    <div class="tutor-fs-7 tutor-color-secondary">Cursos completados</div>
                    <div class="tutor-fs-4 tutor-fw-bold tutor-d-block tutor-d-lg-none tutor-ml-auto">0</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



Y cuando hago lo siguiente me oculta mucho más elementos:


.tutor-col-lg-6 tutor-col-xl-4 tutor-mb-16 tutor-mb-lg-32" {
    display: none;
}




El selector css debe ser asi .tutor-col-lg-6.tutor-col-xl-4.tutor-mb-16.tutor-mb-lg-32 { display: none; } pero si se te desaparecen mas elementos es porque no tienen una clase unica, por ende les terminas pegando a otros, debes darle mas argumentos, como el div padre por ejemplo.

Hola Jefferzon, gracias lo tomaré en cuenta.

El selector .tutor-col-lg-6.tutor-col-xl-4.tutor-mb-16.tutor-mb-lg-32 te está ocultando más elementos porque hay varios que comparten exactamente las mismas clases. Para poder ocultar solo el elemento que mencionas debes añadirle un ID único o, preferiblemente, una clase que lo distinga.
Como plan B, en caso de que no tengas acceso a modificar estos atributos, si estás seguro de que la estructura es consistente, que siempre aparezacan todas las secciones y en el mismo orden, podrías hacerlo con un selector más elaborado.
.tutor-dashboard-content .tutor-dashboard-content-inner:first-of-type .tutor-col-lg-6.tutor-col-xl-4.tutor-mb-16.tutor-mb-lg-32:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}


Nota
Debido a la poca info que se alcanza a ver en la imagen, desconozco si este selector aún vaya a afectar otros elementos que coincidan, aunque conociendo el concepto de lo que se indica deberías poder ajustarlo a la estructura final.
Te dejo unos enlaces informativos en caso de que algo no quede muy claro.

Pseudo-selector
nth-child
Pseudo-selector
first-of-type
Selectores
CSS


Hola Daniel, gracias por tu comentario. Pude hacerlo solo con: .tutor-col-lg-6.tutor-col-xl-4.tutor-mb-16.tutor-mb-lg-32:nth-child(3) dandole "display: none".
